# Backup с использование cmd, проблема с ключом -w

Tags: windows, cmd, bat

Есть сетевая папка, хранящаяся , например, на диске D.
Мне необходимо сделать её копию, например, на диск E.
Объясню проблему, был батник, он обновлял архив, хранящийся на диске E, но при этом сжирал пространство на локальном диске, это не устраивало.
Я решил добавить ключ -w(смысл такой : rar.exe -w E:\temp  E:\archiv D:\papka), вместо этого делался архив E:\ archive в E:\temp. Вопрос : почему?
2 -ой вопрос. Я удалил предыдущий архив, запустил батник , убрав -w, место на локальном диске не сжиралось. Почему?

Comment: В справке производителя указано, что путь рабочей директории указывается сразу посл ключа **w**, без пробела

Comment: Не обратил внимание, спасибо